# Разделить число запятой regexp

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

День добрый! Имеются значения

```
4256, 1200, 568
```

На выходе должно быть, что если 4 цифры в значении то разделять запятой. Если 3 и меньше - оставлять как есть. И В любом случае добавлять знак %. Пример выводы:

```
4,256% , 1,200%, 568%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = [4256, 1200, 568]
for x in s:
    print('{:,}'.format(x))
```